# Will Bio Star Geforce 6100-m9 support 1TB harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

I was wondering if my motherboard, Bio Star Geforce 6100-m9 http://www.biostar-usa.com/mbdetails.asp?model=GEFORCE%206100-M9 will support a 1TB Sata hard drive.
I have tried to find the information on google and also tried to find in the documentation but I do not see anything.

Comment: What makes you think it can't handle it?

Comment: @Ramhound its basically old and im not sure if TB hard drives were available then

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. I only stumbled upon it today...

The Nvidia based SATA controller on this motherboard (and other motherboards that use the same chip) will take any size SATA disk, but it won't accept some SAS disks that run in SATA fall-back mode (most will still work though).

Please note that this SATA controller is only SATA-1 (1.5 Gb/s throughput max) which will limit the throughput of newer SATA-2 and SATA-3 drives.